# For loop - bind dynamic key to the #id

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a for loop that displays the data into multiple radio-buttons (bootstrap):

```
<div class="radio" >
  <label v-for="(choice, index) in choices" v-if="choice.question_id == question.id" :key="choice.id">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio" id="choice.id"> [[choice.content]]
  </label>
</div>
```

As you can see, I wanted to use the `choice.id` for `id="..."` in each button, technically it should look something like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="optradio" id="1"> Choice1
<input type="radio" name="optradio" id="2"> Choice2
<input type="radio" name="optradio" id="3"> Choice3
```

But it renders it with the actual string `choice.id`:

```
<input type="radio" name="optradio" id="choice.id"> Choice1
<input type="radio" name="optradio" id="choice.id"> Choice2
<input type="radio" name="optradio" id="choice.id"> Choice3
```

Forgive my naiveness. Any help/advices? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It renders with `choice-id` string because you  add plain string as the id value, not a variable value

You can use [`v-bind` directive](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/template-syntax.html#attributes) or the shorthand for `v-bind` -> `:id`

```
<div class="radio" >
  <label v-for="(choice, index) in choices" v-if="choice.question_id == question.id" :key="choice.id">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio" v-bind:id="choice.id"> [[choice.content]]
  </label>
</div>
```

using shorthand `<input type="radio" name="optradio" :id="choice.id">`

To answer your questions in the comments.

You can ' separate 'the radios by adding them in a ' group ' using the name attribute. Radios with the same name attribute are in one group. Changing their values won't affect other radios in other groups ( with different name attributes ). See example below.

**Or** you can use [`vue v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) to separate and get the selected options.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#radio-app",
  data: {
    question1: '',
    question2: ''
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools"></script>
Question1:
<input type="radio" name="question1" id="q1choice1" value="choice1"/>
<input type="radio" name="question1" id="q1choice2" value="choice2"/>
Question2:
<input type="radio" name="question2" id="q2choice1" value="choice1"/>
<input type="radio" name="question2" id="q2choice2" value="choice2"/>
<hr />
<h2> Or with VUE v-model </h2>
<div id="radio-app">
Question1:
  <input type="radio" id="q1choice1vue" value="choice1" v-model="question1">
  <input type="radio" id="q1choice2vue" value="choice2" v-model="question1">
Question2:
  <input type="radio" id="q2choice1vue" value="choice1" v-model="question2">
    <input type="radio" id="q2choice2vue" value="choice2" v-model="question2">
  <div>Question 1 selected answer: {{ question1 }}</div>
  <div>Question 2  selected answer: {{ question2 }}</div>
</div>
```

Check more here

- [VUE template syntax](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/template-syntax.html)
- [v-bind directive](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-bind)

Comment: Thank you so much! I still can't accept the answer for the next 8 minutes. I have a small inquiry though; you may have noticed that this radio-buttons that belong in the `choices` object, is under a parent object called `questions`.

Comment: I display the questions via `v-for="(question, index) in questions" :key="question.pk"` and under it is the code in the question. Now if I click radiobutton1 on question1, then click radiobutton5 in question2, the radiobutton1 from question1 gets diselected.

Comment: I thought using unique id's will make those radiobuttons independent. Any thoughts? Thanks a lot again!

Comment: @DranDev glad i could help. You can also use `v-model`. Check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use: `v-bind:id="choice.id"` or the short version `:id="choice.id"`